# Histograma con Python

Tags: python, plotly

Estoy buscando una forma de representar de una manera sencilla el siguiente DataFrame:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero obtener es el histograma, donde en el eje x aparezca una vez cada elemento distinto en el index, y dos barras en cada uno de ellos, una para event_launch con su valor en count2 y otra para event_play con su valor en count2.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Perfecto, creando un caso de ejemplo parecido al tuyo se logra obtener los histogramas de la siguiente manera.

Primero creamos un `DataFrame` parecido al tuyo

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# creamos dataframe parecido al de la pregunta
tier1 = ['a' if i % 2 == 0 else 'b' for i in range(12)]  # ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
count2 = (np.random.rand(12)*10000).astype(int)  # array([3348,  800, 4133, 3449, 4293, 3204, 1802, 4784, 6168, 7057, 4123, 1380])
data = np.asarray([tier1, count2]).swapaxes(0, 1)  # shape (filas: 12, columnas: 3)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['tier1', 'count2']
```

Todo esto para generar un dataframe en `df` como el siguiente:

```
   tier1 count2
0      a   9306
1      b    362
2      a   1441
3      b   9451
4      a   1671
5      b   6545
6      a   7499
7      b   3421
8      a   8961
9      b   3148
10     a   7617
11     b    886
```

Ahora, dirigiéndonos al meollo del asunto, el lo primero que hay que hacer es un filtrado o una selección de las filas que cumplan la condición que necesitamos, en este caso, que el valor de la columna '`tier1`' sea de un valor u otro. Por ejemplo, usamos `'a'` y `'b'`.

```
# Ahora para filtrar por cada tipo de 'tier1' se hace lo siguiente
filtrado_a = df[df['tier1'] == 'a']  # filtramos df por los indices que cumplen la condicion que el valor de tier1 es igual a 'a'
filtrado_b = df[df['tier1'] == 'b']  # analogo
```

en filtrado_a queda:

```
   tier1 count2
0      a   9306
2      a   1441
4      a   1671
6      a   7499
8      a   8961
10     a   7617
```

Finalmente, ya tenemos los `DataFrame` filtrados por nuestros criterios como se muestra arriba. Procedemos a obtener le histograma extrayendo los valores de la columna `'count2'` como se muestra a continuación:

```
# ahora basta con obtener el histograma de los valores de la columna 'count2', para ello ocuparemos numpy.histogram que genera los bins automaticamente
histograma_a = np.histogram(filtrado_a['count2'].astype(int))  # histograma de columna 'count2' que tenian 'tier1' == 'a'
histograma_b = np.histogram(filtrado_b['count2'].astype(int))  # histograma de columna 'count2' que tenian 'tier1' == 'b'

print(histograma_a)
# (array([2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2], dtype=int64), array([1441. , 2227.5, 3014. , 3800.5, 4587. , 5373.5, 6160. , 6946.5,
       # 7733. , 8519.5, 9306. ]))
```